# How do I make onclick event skip to offclick?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, touchscreen

I am making a virtual keyboard for a touchscreen computer. I am using angular, html, and css only. How do I make it so that when I touch a key, even if I am holding the key down, the click is forced to "lift the mouse up."

The reason I am asking this is because when touching 2 characters within 500ms-1000ms, it ends up not registering a click.

If you have any tips about improving touchscreen usability feel free to comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Open this demo on a touch device to test: **http://jsbin.com/nibohe/4/**

To get a **native app feel** (touch / mouse) UX:

```
$keybKeyElement.on("touchstart mousedown", function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Capture the key
    // Send character to textarea
    // other stuff
});
```

If you use only the `click` event on a touchscreen you have to

- wait user's ~300+ ms for the *up* movement
- ~400ms delay for the browser to make it a valid click event.

where `touchstart` end `event.preventDefault` will kill the `click`, `mousedown` or other events used on desktop (non/touch) machines.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `onmouseup` instead of `onclick`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: He asked for a way to get the action to happen when the mouse button came up. That is what `onmouseup` does. I don't see how that is not an answer. The question does not say if he has tried `onmouseup` so I suggested it.

Do I need to provide links in my answer for clarification or do I need to add more explanation? I would like to know so I can answer better in the future.